# conditional comments in html

Tags: html, css, comments, conditional-statements

could you please tell me where is the mistake. I cant see any text in conditional comments in any browser.

```
web.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<head/>
<body>
    <!--[if !IE]>
        <p><span class="p-style">XXXXXXXXXXXX</span></p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
        <p><span class="p-style-IE">YYYYYYYYYYYYY</span></p>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
</html>

style.css
.p-style {
    color:red;
}

.p-style-IE {
    color:green;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers other than IE treat the conditional statements as comments because they're enclosed inside comment tags.

```
<!--[if IE]>
Non-IE browsers ignore this
<![endif]-->
```

However, when you're targeting a browser that is NOT IE you have to use 2 comments, one before and one after the code. IE will ignore the code between them, whereas other browsers will treat it as normal code. The syntax for targeting non-IE browsers is therefore:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
IE ignores this
<!--[endif]-->
```

Your code has some problems and I corrected them. Check with IE9 and other browsers. Now its working fine except in IE10 and higher (cuz IE10 and above no longer support conditional tags)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<head/>
<body>
 <p><span class="p-style">XXXXXXXXXXXX</span></p>
 <p><span class="p-style-IE">YYYYYYYYYYYYY</span></p>
     <!--[if IE]>
    <style>
    .p-style {color:red;}
    .p-style-IE {display: none;}
   </style> 
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !IE]><!-->
   <style>
    .p-style {display: none;}
    .p-style-IE{color:green;}
   </style> 
   <!--<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Update : For IE10 and IE11,**

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
}
```

we create a media query using -ms-high-contrast, in which you place your IE10+ specific CSS styles. Because -ms-high-contrast is Microsoft-specific (and only available in IE10+), it will only be parsed in Internet Explorer 10 and greater.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there some way to write code especially for IE10 or Microsoft Edge? I have code which works fine with Mozilla, Chrome and Opera but some elements are a little bit shifted in Explorer and Edge. I dont know how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks and if somebody looks for Microsoft Edge hack, this works  _:-ms-lang(x), _:-webkit-full-screen, .selector { property:value;}